# speeding up (rewriting?) a not in sub select query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

From a table I'm trying to get

a) users who fulfil certain criteria which is held in a key/value combination in a table

OR

b) users who do not have that key/value combination at all

So, for example, to try and find users who live in France or who have not yet added their location, I'm using this (simplified) query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    current_users
    JOIN current_users um_location ON current_users.id = um_location.id
WHERE
    (
        ( um_location.meta_key = 'location' AND um_location.meta_value = 'France' )
    OR 
        ( current_users.id NOT IN  
            (SELECT current_users.id FROM current_users WHERE current_users.meta_key = 'location' ) 
        )
    )
```

The problem is, of course, that running the OR sub-select query (if that's what it's called) is slowing down the query hugely. And since the full query has about 5 or 6 of these sub-selects, it's slowing things down far too much.

Is there another way of doing this perhaps? A faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Change your OR condition as a UNION query instead of OR

```
SELECT * FROM
    current_users
    JOIN current_users um_location ON current_users.id = um_location.id
WHERE
    um_location.meta_key = 'location' AND um_location.meta_value = 'France' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM
    current_users
    JOIN current_users um_location ON current_users.id = um_location.id
WHERE
    current_users.id NOT IN  
    (SELECT current_users.id FROM current_users WHERE 
    current_users.meta_key='location' )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the most succinct possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM current_users
LEFT JOIN current_users AS um_location 
   ON current_users.id = um_location.id
   AND um_location.meta_key = 'location' 
WHERE um_location.meta_value = 'France' 
   OR um_location.meta_value IS NULL
;
```

...but as isaace answer hints, MySQL does not handle OR conditions ideally.
So, this might perform better.

```
SELECT *
FROM current_users
LEFT JOIN current_users AS um_location 
   ON current_users.id = um_location.id
   AND um_location.meta_key = 'location' 
WHERE um_location.meta_value = 'France' 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM current_users
LEFT JOIN current_users AS um_location 
   ON current_users.id = um_location.id
   AND um_location.meta_key = 'location' 
WHERE um_location.meta_value IS NULL
;
```

..but it will probably only make a difference if you have meta_value indexed; as the issue is that MySQL tends to ignore indexes when presented with OR.

---

Edit: Due to the type of schema design begin used, there might be some weird issues with these queries using "location" entries as rows on the left side of the join; try this instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM current_users AS non_location
LEFT JOIN current_users AS um_location 
   ON current_users.id = um_location.id
   AND um_location.meta_key = 'location' 
WHERE non_location.meta_key != 'location'
   AND (um_location.meta_value = 'France' 
        OR um_location.meta_value IS NULL
       )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you both for your suggestions. Unfortunately I couldn't get them to work as the join

```
LEFT JOIN current_users AS um_location 
ON current_users.id = um_location.id
AND um_location.meta_key = 'location'
```

did not return the records of those users who hadn't yet entered their location.

However, after a lot of work I managed to solve the issue. It's not elegant but it works:

1. Create a temporary table with a subset of the users who fulfil some basic criteria.
2. Do a simple INSERT IGNORE INTO ... SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM current_users adding in the missing 'location' with dummy information.

Then the final query includes this:

```
um_location.meta_value = 'France'
or
um_location.meta_value = 'dummyinfo'
```

It's not blisteringly fast but since this is a process which acts in the back end for admin users only they can afford to wait... ;)

Again, thanks for your help!